# What is the purpose of the PHP_DEBUG Constant?

Tags: php, constants

This is probably a stupid question, but I couldn't find any other info on this topic. What exactly is the purpose of `PHP_DEBUG` and the majority of other [Predefined Constants](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php)?

When I echo `PHP_DEBUG` I just see a 0. I'm not sure what significance this has .. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PHP_DEBUG` is an indication of whether your PHP binary was compiled in a debug configuration. If all you are doing with PHP is writing PHP programs then it's useless to you.

You can see from [the source](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_4/main/main.c#2107) that the PHP constant `PHP_DEBUG` mirrors the value of the macro with the same name in the C sources, which in turn affects how PHP is built.

Comment: Nice explanation, thank you - that helped! Interesting to see the PHP source as well :)

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](http://tosbourn.com/2010/04/php/php_debug-a-very-handy-little-constant/), maybe that helps?

Not sure what the point of it is, versus actually defining something similar yourself...

It might also mean that PHP was compiled with debugging symbols enabled (--enable-debug).